# shell script to read a list of files and copy to a directory

Tags: unix, command

I'm trying to figure out a script file that takes in a file containing list of files and then copy only these files to a different directory. Any help would be appreiated.

Comment: `while read file; do cp $file /other/dir; done < file_name` should make it.

Comment: You can also use xargs:
`cat file | xargs -I {} cp {} /other/dir`
(taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26397688/3150964))

Answer (score 2):

```
for i in `cat file`
do
cp $i /other/
done
```

Comment: it just copies the same list with the name of the files to the new directory. not the actual files. any suggestions please?

Answer (score 2):

`cpio -pmu /new/directory < file`

Assuming you have `cpio` installed, anyway...

Answer (score 0):

```
    file="/work/file.txt"

    for j in `cat $file`

    do

      cp ${j} /destination/direc

    done
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment, therefore expanding slightly on fedorqui's answer, this adds quoting to handle filenames with spaces:

```
#!/bin/bash

destination="./output_files"

while read file
do
    echo $file
    cp "$file" $destination
done < input_files
```